# how to display loaded objects during session of batch load .obj file in Blender using script

Tags: python

I can load *.obj from one directory using python script in VSCode, using sth like:

```
for item in obj_list:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(path_to_obj_dir, item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = path_to_file)
```

but Blender updates viewport only after all objects are loaded. During the whole session, it seems all objects are loaded into cache? Is it possible to load one object then display it in the viewport ?then load 2nd object,.....

ThX

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)`